# How to animate the text on cells in edit mode in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, uilabel

I have custom table cell with two labels on left and right corner of the cell.

Now when I enter edit mode, as we all know, the cell shifts towards right, so my text on right label also shifts to right and it will become invisible.

But what I want is that it should animate itself in edit mode, similar to what the mail application does in edit mode, where the text shifts and will still be visible.

Please help me out in solving this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your labels are subviews of the contentView of those cells.

From `UITableViewCell Class Reference`

> contentView Returns the content view of the cell object. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly, retain) UIView *contentView

Also make sure the `autoresizingMask` of the entire cell content (labels, views, controls) is setup correctly to adapt to changes in layout - e.g. `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth`

Comment: hi Till thanks for your response..can u please explain me in detail..I didnt get you ...

Comment: I am assuming that your custom labels on the UITableViewCell are directly added as subviews to the cell which is a common mistake. Instead, add them to the UITableViewCell's contentView which will make them animate properly. Also make sure the label's autoresizing mask is correctly setup (e.g. UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth).

Comment: hey thanks till ,u mean to say that if I add the label to cell's content view..it will take care of the animation on editing mode and my label text will be visible?

Comment: correct the animation will result into a proper formatting when using contentView as the host of your custom controls (e.g. your labels).

Comment: hey Till I have three files customtablecell.h,customtablecell.m and customtablecell.xib,so here I have defined the IBoutlets for the my labels.then in my tableviewcontroller.m ,I am calling this customcell,so I have a doubt,where shall i add the labels to the content view..in customcell.m or tableviewcontroller.m

Comment: Hey Till ,I got the solution..I have to write the code of autoresizemask and it works perfectly

Comment: If my answer was helpful and solved your problem, you should check it with the checkmark to mark it as solved.